# Server returns 201 but promise routes to error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have a service called AuthService that makes a post request to login

the server response with a 201 but the second function in then() is executed and not the first

```
 AuthService.login(credentials)
    .then(function(data){
        console.log("Login success====")
        console.log(data);
        //if its successful
        $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess);
        $scope.setCurrentUser(user);

        $state.go('dashboard.account');  
    }, function(error){  // THIS IS EXECUTED ONCE SERVER RESPONDS
        console.log("Login error====")
        //$rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginFailed);
        console.log('Error: ' + error);
     });
```

So I get "Login error===" instead of success. I'm not sure why I'm following this guide

https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec

I thought that 201 are successful

Error contains

```
Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

//Session is a service that stores user data

```
.factory('AuthService', function ($http, Session) {
   var authService = {};

   authService.login = function (credentials) {
     return $http
     .post('/login', credentials)
     .then(function (res) {
        Session.create(res.data.id, res.data.user.id,
                   res.data.user.role);
        return res.data.user;
   });
};
```

Comment: And what does the `error` variable contain?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is helpful, but "Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined". If the server is sending back 201 I'm not sure why it's entering error in the first place

Comment: Can you post the code for `AuthService.login`?

Comment: The error is in the line `Session.create(res.data.id, res.data.user.id, res.data.user.role);`. Your `res` object does not have a `data` property or a `data.user` property.

Comment: hm okay thank you that makes sense, I didn't realize the second function could still be called if there is an error inside authService.login. Promises are hard ;(

Comment: The second function is the error callback, so if there's an error (any kind of error), it will be called.